# Laravel 7 not require file

Tags: laravel-7

'''Fatal error: require():Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Diplomado.PHP\grupo-3-pagina-administrativa-de-laboratorio-cl-nico\vendor\composer/../../app/Mail/MessageContact' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Diplomado.PHP\grupo-3-pagina-administrativa-de-laboratorio-cl-nico\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 69'''

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I don't know where exactly the error is.
it just shows me that I should import that file and I'm doing it